# What .Net wrappers are there for Lua? (Not a poll)

Tags: c#, .net, lua

What .Net wrappers are there for Lua? Google wasn't too helpful, although that could just be my lack of talent with search terms.

What I'm looking for: Lua and LuaBind in .Net, for use with C#. Direct conversion would be best; (a) wrapper(s) would be acceptable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You find these by appending ".net" to the language name.  Google "lua.net", take the second hit.  Straight from the guys that made it.

Comment: I saw that. Thought it was a spam site because of the site design. Edit: Lua2IL isn't available; guess that solves the question of what to download.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/).